# Facebook - Reload iframe without show confirm diaglog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-iframe

I want to reload my webpage in an iframe  (`location.reload();`) but Facebook always show a confirm dialog. I want to prevent this dialog from showing. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first redirect the user to any page via `GET`. That is a safety mechanism implemented into the browser and can not be disabled via JS.

Answer (score 0):

I now use `parent.location.href` instead of `location.reload();`